# Where did these OpenGL ES XCode performance detectives go?

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I just watched a WWDIC on OpenGL es that had Xcode version 4.  I was so pumped to learn about all these cool tools that Xcode has (because I am having some really weird performance issues), however I can't find most of them.

I can't find the part of Xcode where their is an "Analyze Performance" button that runs experiments on your frame a bunch of time (varying things) until it gets you a list of things effecting your performance such as shaders.

Also when I opened up my app in Instruments GL Tool I can not find the part where it tells how long each gl command takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from my understanding these tools are now built into the frame capture, however I personally see them as having less data then shown in the WWDIC talk.  Oh well!